# Python: save image classification results while keeping the original filename

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm trying to save images with original filenames from classification model. The code below works, but it saves the classified images with new filenames. Any help would deeply appreciate.

```py
import os
import cv2
import keras
import numpy as np

from keras.models import load_model
new_model = load_model('/path/to/mymodel.h5')

test_dir = '/path/to/test-set'
test_imgs = ['/path/to/test-set/{}'.format(i) for i in os.listdir(test_dir)]

def read_and_process_image(list_of_images):

  X = []

  for image in list_of_images:
      img = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
      X.append(cv2.resize(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), 
              (299, 299), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))

  return X

X_test = read_and_process_image(test_imgs)
x = np.array(X_test)
test_datagent = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

class_names = ['neg','pos']
i = 100
plt.figure(figsize=(30,20))
for batch in test_datagent.flow(x, batch_size=1):
    pred = new_model.predict(batch)
    for j in range(len(batch)):
        plt.subplot(100, 1, i+1)
        plt.title(class_names[np.argmax(pred[j])])
        imgplot = plt.imshow(batch[0])
        plt.imsave(('/path/to/output/ {}.jpg'.format(
        class_names[np.argmax(pred[j])] + str(i))), batch[j])

        i -=1
        if i == -1:
             break
```

Comment: Can you provide 2-3 input filenames and output filenames that you actually used?  And what paths did you use for input and output?  Also what values do you get at line: [class_names[np.argmax(pred[j])] + str(i))), batch[j]]?  Can you print this out for the same 2-3 filenames?  Code looks good on cursory inspection.  I am also studying image deep learning, so would be interested in this.

Comment: You haven't defined 'new_model'. Also you should include your import statements for `os, cv2, np` etc.

Comment: @JenniferYoon It prints out e.g. pos0.jpg, pos1.jpg etc.

Comment: @RobKwasowski Yes, they are imported in the full code that I didn't provide them here for being short. But my problem is how to save those output images with their original filenames.

Comment: But for someone coming along and trying to help it would make things a lot simpler if you put your import statements at the top so then I know what modules I need to install to test your code. And you still haven't defined `new_model` so without that I can't test it.

Comment: @RobKwasowski I updated. The "new_model" is the one I have trained on my images, then I load it again to do prediction.

Comment: @Dio  Thanks, what were you expecting as output saved file names for pos0.jpg and pos1.jpg?  
And just out of curiosity, can you try indenting your continuation line after ".format(" , the line, the line starting "class_names[np.argmanx(..." by 4 spaces?  I am not sure if the program is confused here.  Maybe your original code is already indented on the continuation line, not sure.

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Comment: @RobKwasowski yes :(